# Why are my lights always "Updating" in Apple Home?

Tags: homekit

Over the past weeks, after working pretty reliably for several months, my Hue lights spend most of the time "Updating" (and unusable) in Apple Home. Restarting and force-restarting the Home app does nothing, nor does restarting the iPhone.

[image]

Is this a known bug? Is there a fix?

Comment: It's not a system I've ever used, but if everything is down, I'd suspect the Hue Bridge rather than the phone.

Comment: @Tetsujin: The Hue Bridge is working fine and I can control everything with all the other apps on my phone that use it (Hue, SmartThings, etc.).